# google map place API how to remove country name from suggestion

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When we type a location or address the autocomplete will show the country name in its suggestion. Is there way to remove or omit country name from suggestions?

[image]

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626727/google-places-javascript-autocomplete-can-i-remove-the-country-from-the-place-n

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the [`AutocompletePrediction` object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#AutocompletePrediction) returned by  [`AutocompleteService`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.21/reference#AutocompleteService). The relevant properties of `AutocompletePrediction` are:

- `description` (Type:  string. This is the unformatted version of the query suggested by the Places service.)
- `terms` (Type:  Array
  Information about individual terms in the above description, from most to least specific. For example, "Taco Bell", "Willitis", and "CA".)

So you can modify the response changing one of the two properties, for instance removing the country by splicing the description `prediction.description.split(", ").slice(0,-1)`

For the example below I used a JQuery UI widget as a wrapper for the AutocompleteService following https://stackoverflow.com/a/13774273/2314737

```js
$(function() {
  $("#search").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
      service.getPlacePredictions({
        input: request.term,
        type: 'geocode',
      }, function(predictions, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          alert(status);
          return;
        }
        response($.map(predictions, function(prediction, i) {
          return {
            value: prediction.description,
            //label: prediction.terms[0].value
            label: prediction.description.split(", ").slice(0,-1),             
          }
        }));
      });
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=placeshttps://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="search">Search:</label>
  <input id="search">
</div>
```